# Twitter Web Intents - Chrome Tweet Button - Login & Tweet Issue

Tags: twitter, tweets

I have a Tweet Button on my website as described in [this article](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview). I am trying out the below use case from the button under the subject `Tweet creation flow`.

1. Logout from Twitter.
2. Click on the button.
3. Enter username and password, click on `Log in and Tweet`.
4. Twitter redirects the user to a [new page](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet) with no query parameters hence the textarea is not auto-filled with the Tweet passed.

The above use case is working fine in Firefox. Any insight about this behavior in Chrome? Can this be considered as a bug from Twitter?

Comment: did you find any solution, i am also facing same issue for chrome, firefox is working fine with this

Comment: well this is auto fixed now from twitter